# How to get current row cell value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I add following button to each row in the table in `showPosition` function.

```
<button class="btn btn-primary" id="showOnMap" onclick="locateOnMap()">Show on Map</button>
```

In following `locateOnMap` function I need to get second and third cell value of current row.

```
function locateOnMap() {
            alert($(this).closest('tr').find('td').eq(1).text());
        }
```

`showPosition` method runs continuesly and add multiple rows.

```
function showPosition(position) {
    var table = document.getElementById("gpstable");
                var row = table.insertRow(1);
                var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
                var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
                var cell3 = row.insertCell(2);
                var cell4 = row.insertCell(3);
                cell1.innerHTML = Date();
                cell2.innerHTML = position.coords.latitude;
                cell3.innerHTML = position.coords.longitude;
                cell4.innerHTML = "";
                var bt = document.getElementById("showOnMap").cloneNode();
                var cell5 = row.insertCell(4);
                cell5.appendChild(bt);
}
```

Comment: Could we see the table? :) (the html)

Comment: FYI, IDs must be unique on document context

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about adding these two values as `data-` attributes on the button each time before you add it:

```
<button class="btn btn-primary showOnMap" data-lat="stuff" data-lon="things" onclick="locateOnMap()">Show on Map</button>
```

and then accessing them with something like this:

```
function locateOnMap() {
    var btn = $(this);
    var lat = btn.data('lat');
    var lon = btn.data('lon');
}
```

Code for showPosition would look something like this:

```
function showPosition(position) {
    var table = $("#gpstable");
    var row = table.insertRow(1);
    var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
    var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
    var cell3 = row.insertCell(2);
    var cell4 = row.insertCell(3);
    cell1.innerHTML = Date();
    cell2.innerHTML = position.coords.latitude;
    cell3.innerHTML = position.coords.longitude;
    cell4.innerHTML = "";
    var bt = $("#showOnMap").clone();
    bt.data("lat", position.coords.latitude);
    bt.data("lon", position.coords.longitude);
    var cell5 = row.insertCell(4);
    cell5.appendChild(bt);
}
```